# Manytoone mapping for two tables to the single entity

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
Class A{
private int campid;
private string name;
}

Class B {
Private int campid;
Private string name;
}`


Class combo{
private int id;
private string phonenumber;
}
```

I'm trying like this

```
Class A{
private int campid;
private string name;
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Combo.class,mappedBy ="a",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
private Combo combo;
}

Class B {
Private int campid;
Private string name;
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Combo.class,mappedBy ="b",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
private Combo combo;
}`

Class combo{
private int id;
private string phonenumber;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Camp_Id_fk",insertable=true, updatable=true)
private  A a;
    
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Camp_Id_fk",insertable=true, updatable=true)
private B b;
}
```

want to store the campid of class A and campid class B as the foreign key in the combo table. One campid can have multiple phone numbers.

I want to do this in spring jpa..I'm not understanding how to do it

Comment: What did you try? Did you look at the [`@ManyToMany`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html) annotation? Show us your trials.

Comment: In order to help people quickly understand what it is you are trying to achieve, it is best to open your question with a short summary rather than a code block.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "camp_id")
    private Long campid;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "a_combo",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "camp _id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private Set<Combo> comboSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

And same for B class

Comment: how it will map to the table combo

Comment: Will be two tables for relationships between "a and combo" and "b and combo" "a_combo", "b_combo", which contains "camp_id", "combo_id"

Comment: I want both A table campid and b table campid to map in combo table as the foreign key in the same column